# How to get the public instance address from knife ec2 server create with chef-solo

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef, knife

I'd like to somehow get the public instance address or hostname from `knife ec2 create ...`, but I can't find any mechanism for doing so.

Since I'm currently using `chef-solo`, I've written a simple script that runs `knife ec2 create` with a bootstrap template to prepare the node for `chef-solo`.  At the midpoint of that script (after `knife ec2 create` has finished), I need to copy and paste the public IP for the instance, which is then used to "push" to the node (copies the cookbooks, roles, data_bags, host-dna, etc up to the node and runs `chef-solo`).

When you bootstrap a node with `chef-client` and `chef-server`, you don't have this problem, because the new node reaches out to the `chef-server` and pulls it config.  But I'd prefer to stick with `chef-solo` for now.

Comment: I don't think I understand - who needs to know about the public IP address? Your bootstrap script, or the node itself in some config file?

Comment: My script needs to know the public IP address. It first runs `knife ec2 create ...`, then pushes the chef files with rsync, then runs chef-solo via ssh.  But rsync and ssh can't run unless the script knows the public IP or hostname.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm working around this at the moment with a policy of never using the same "Name" tag on more than one server at a time, and using a simple ruby fog script that pulls the list of servers and finds the server with the appropriate "Name" tag.

Comment: I guess another way to do this would be to `tee` the output of `knfe ec2 server create` to a dump file, and when it completes, grep the output file for the public hostname line, etc.

Comment: @nicholasa.evans Rather than have a policy about unique "name" tags, I think I'm going to get a list of active servers and sort by creation date. I'll assume the most recent is the one I want. This would seem to work so long as very few people are working with the account :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AESDG-chapter-instancedata.html

Something like:

wget http:// 169.254.169.254 /latest/meta-data/public-hostname

or change the last part to

public-ipv4